# how to change the installation path of ionic frasmework in command prompot

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic, I have installed my ionic to C:\Users\myname, now I don't install ionic under user name folder, because it make my folder mess and i want to put them to one directory, meanwhile, i don't want to uninstall my ionic and corvoda and install them again !

does anyone have any solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install ionic and cordova using npm repository globally.First install node.js and follow the below instructions https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/